# Should I close makefile'ed socket and it is original socket independently?

Tags: python, file, sockets

[Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) says that;

> socket.**makefile**([mode[, bufsize]])
>  Return a file object associated
>   with the socket. (File objects are described in File Objects.) The
>   file object references a dup()ped version of the socket file
>   descriptor, so the file object and socket object may be closed or
>   garbage-collected independently.

Does it mean I have to close both socket and file like this?

```
conn = socket.create_connection((addr,port))
myfile = conn.makefile()
myfile.close()
conn.close()
```

Or closing one is sufficient? If so, does it matter which one I close and which one I don't?

Comment: Sounds like "independently" means they should both be closed.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation says, both objects are independent. The underlying connection is closed only if all file descriptors related to it are closed.  You must close both.  Use the `with` statement to manage such resources.

Comment: Using them with `with` statement gives me `AttributeError: __exit__` on Python 2.7.3

Comment: Socket objects in 2.7.3 don't have context support. Needs to be custom. You can use `with contextlib.closing(aSocket)`

Comment: @yasar11732 Sorry, I should have mentioned this.  Wrap socket objects in `contextlib.closing()`, as jdi suggested.